# alfresco update custom property in java backed webscript

Tags: java, properties, alfresco

I have created a custom aspect having a property for person data type in contentModel.xml

```
<aspect name="cm:CustomAspect">
 <title>CustomAspect</title>
 <properties>

    <property name="cm:updateDate">
       <title>updateDate</title>
       <type>d:date</type>
    </property>

 </properties>
</aspect>



 <type name="cm:person">
         <title>Person</title>
     <mandatory-aspects>
        <aspect>cm:CustomAspect</aspect>
        <aspect>cm:auditable</aspect>
     </mandatory-aspects>
  </type>
```

I want  to set in java backed webscript  the "updateDate" property. 
In javascript webscript i would do :  `person.properties.updateDate = new Date();` but i don't know how to do this in java backed webscript.

I'm using personService class to achive  the update.

```
Map newUserProp  =  new HashMap();
newUserProp.put(QNAME_DATE_UPDATE, new Date());
personService.setPersonProperties(username, newUserProp);
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `NodeService`:

```
// member of your Java class
private ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

// in your method
NodeService nodeService = serviceRegistry.getNodeService();
nodeService.setProperty(nodeRef, QNAME_DATE_UPDATE, new Date());
```

Comment: As the OP is wanting to set it for a person, you probably need to add the code to get the Person's NodeRef via the PersonService first

Answer (score 1):

- Fetch person NodeRef.
- Get all his properties map.
- Add your property into that map and set that map again in user.

  ```
  NodeRef userNodeRef = personService.getPerson(userLoginName);
  Map<QName, Serializable> userPropertyMap = nodeService.getProperties(userNodeRef);
                          userPropertyMap.put(QNAME_DATE_UPDATE, new Date());
              personService().setPersonProperties(userLoginName, userPropertyMap);
  ```

Hope this helps. Do not forget to inject personservice and nodeservice in your context file, add getter setter for those services in your spring bean.